# Why i am getting " UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment "

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Whenever I am trying to run this code

```
def BinToHex(x):
    a = hex(int(x,2))
    return a[2:]

def HexToBin(x):
    b = bin(int(x,16))[2:]
    return b

c = 0
with open("input.txt") as l:
    for line in l:
        c += 1
    l.close()

x = ""

def main():
    Write = open("binary.txt","w")
    Read = open("input.txt", "r")
    for i in range(c):
        bakwaas = Read.readline()
        d = bakwaas.split()
        opcode = d[0]
        address = d[1]
        li = {"cla":"7800","cma":"7400","inc":"7200","hlt":"7100","inp":"f800","out":"f400","ski":"f200","sko":"f100","ion":"f080","iof":"f040"}
        la = {"and":"000","lda":"010","add":"001","sta":"011","bun":"100","call":"101","sub":"110"}
        if opcode in li:
            u = li[opcode]
            hexaNum1 = HexToBin(u)
            if len(hexaNum1) == 16:
                hexaNum1 = hexaNum1
            else:
                hexaNum1 = "0" + hexaNum1
            Write.write(hexaNum1)
            x += hexaNum1
            Write.write("\n")
        else:
            hexaNum2 = address[:3]
            arr = opcode[:3]
            ad = la[arr]
            if opcode[-1]=="#":
                ad = "0" + ad
            elif opcode[-1]=="@":
                ad = "1" + ad
            temp = ad
            bintemp = HexToBin(hexaNum2)
            hextemp = BinToHex(ad)
            ad = hextemp + bintemp
            temp = "000" + temp + bintemp
            Write.write(temp)
            x  += temp 
            Write.write("\n")


    Write.close()
    Read.close()
    String = x
    BitInString = [String[i:i + 8] for i in range(0, len(String), 8)]
    BytesInString = [int(i,2) for i in BitInString]
    with open("output.bin", "wb") as l:
        l.write(bytearray(BytesInString))
    l.close()
main()
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "exercise.py", line 63, in
>   
>       main()   File "exercise.py", line 51, in main
>       x  += temp  UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment

I was assigned an assignment to recreate assembler which can read Machine language in a higher language of our choice. So, I am reading the code content from text and reading as well as writing in a binary file.

my text file contains
and@ 123

as for the output I should be getting a file with a size of 2 bytes and 0001000100100011 in a binary file according to my input.
I am not able to understand what is this error trying to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

`x += hexaNum1` translates to `x = x + hexaNum1` (same for `x += temp`), so it needs `x` to be defined before the operation, otherwise it would not know which value to add.

You can easily fix this by adding a `x = 0` before your `for` loop (provided that you want the starting value of `x` to be the integer default, `0`)